# What is the cheapest way to pull the data from bitcoind/bitcoin-core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I am wondering if there is a cheap way to scrape the bitcoind data. I am using a remote server and cannot spend too much time running this program otherwise it would be expensive. I am wondering if there is a way to speed up the RPC scraping (meaning a setting like `dbache` which could DRASTICALLY speed things up) which I wrote a python script or another way to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to parse the blockchain yourself? Just parse blk*.dat files

Comment: I know that is possible, I was wondering if you have any suggestions on that. It would take long to do this. Also how would you scrape the value of the inputs since you have to reference a previous transaction? I have not found much documentation on this.@amaclin